# Add custom app on desk using Frappe + ERP

Tags: python, erp, erpnext, frappe

So i was a beginner using this framework.

I don't know how to add custom app on the desk.

I was following the tutorial by add desk.py and insert my code there. after bench migrate and nothing happend. I'm following tutorial from [this link](https://github.com/frappe/frappe/wiki/Using-Desk-Modules,-Calendar-and-List-View-in-Frappe-Framework).

Comment: please add your code what you have tried and try to ask a specific section

Answer (score 1):

[Check This Link](https://github.com/frappe/erpnext/blob/develop/erpnext/config/accounts.py)

You have to create .py file into the config folder with the module name

Your Custom app_name>app_name>config>[app_name.py]>and then add code